# TextWriterTraceListener not working as expected when adding to System.Diagnostics.Debug.Listeners

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, debugging, system.diagnostics

Full Program:

```
Option Strict On : Option Explicit On Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        'System.Diagnostics.Debug.Listeners.Add(New System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener("C:\a.txt"))
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Listeners.Add(New System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener("a.txt"))
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("asd")
    End Sub

End Module
```

After I ran it, I had a file a.txt in my debug folder but the size is 0 bytes (and when i open it is empty of course)

Shouldn't the output had "asd" in it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add one or more

```
 System.Diagnostics.Debug.Flush()
```

statements, and/or a

```
 System.Diagnostics.Debug.Close()
```

when closing that App.

Comment: Yes, .AutoFlush = True (from memory)

Answer (score 0):

I have found this issue also a long time ago. You can get [around](http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/articles/81629.aspx) flushing every time if you are willing to use a CriticalFinalizer.